# How to find if a Oracle table column is encrypted with AES (Obfuscation Toolkit)

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption

In the Oracle db i am using, some columns are encrypted like Birth date. But there is no data in all_encrypted_columns. I got to know that the encryption used is Oracle AES. I need to have a program that will check the tables and list out the columns that are encrypted. How can I do this?

Below post talks about TDE. Since all_encrypted_columns are empty i guess this is not encrypted with TDE. 
[Oracle - How to determine if a table is TDE encrypted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46665338/oracle-how-to-determine-if-a-table-is-tde-encrypted)

Comment: *"In the Oracle db i am using, some columns are encrypted like Birth date. But there is no data in all_encrypted_columns."* if thats the case a (web) application might have encrypted  it then?

Comment: This seems like a kind of XY problem, shouldn't you or another person working on this project(s) already know which columns should be encrypted? If that info isn't anywhere, I think it should so that you shouldn't have to detect it

Comment: @RaymondNijland I am also doubting that, web application is maintained by a team with a different vendor

Comment: @Kaddath by querying we can see which columns are encrypted. But i am trying to create a script that would go through a big list of tables (~800) and print out some details about the schema and columns. So dynamically we need to find if column is encrypted.